# Diffie Hellman and AES on Android

Tags: flutter, android, encryption, aes, diffie-hellman

I am trying to use Diffie Hellman for key exchange and `AES` to encrypt data with keys. Can anyone provide me a suitable work sample for android ?

Answer (score 3):

I've actually been working on a similar problem lately myself. I don't have a working sample, but here are some points you should be aware of:

1. Android uses a partial Bouncy Castle package to handle most of its cryptography, but some people prefer to user their own cryptographic package (Spongy Castle is a commonly cited alternative) since Android's is incomplete. See [the discussion in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488658/can-i-use-latest-bouncycastle-provider-on-android).
2. If you choose to use Android's existing tools, you can access them through [Cipher](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html). Here is a [useful list of algorithms Android supports](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a4c3673dee73eac8?fwc=1).
3. Be aware that if you choose to use some non-Android Java crypto library, Android does not support all Java packages your library may need. See [my (currently unanswered) question about how to deal with that in Spongy Castle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898801/how-to-include-the-spongy-castle-jar-in-android).

Hope these help!